# How to use the getColor method from cwac's ColorMixer?

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I am trying to implement the get color method for the cwac color mixer( https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-colormixer), but every time this code runs I get a `NullPointerException`:

```
int color = 1;

public void openColor(){
ColorMixer mixer = (ColorMixer)findViewById(R.id.mixer);
  if (color!=1){
    mixer.setColor(color);
  }
  color = mixer.getColor();
}
```

The `color = mixer.getColor();`     is the line that crashes.

Comment: You're most likely not searching for the `ColorMixer` in the right place(or your layout doesn't have a `ColorMixer` element with the id `R.id.mixer`).

Comment: Thank you luksprog - it turned out it was crashing because I was trying to run the openColor method within a pop up window, and what I needed to do was not use a separate method and instead put the name of my pop up window (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595427/android-popup-and-button-to-dismiss-doesnt-work) - I will add this as an answer as soon as I can (people like me who can't answer any questions can't post an answer within 8 hours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't ever used this Commonsware component before, but from looking at the [source code](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-colormixer/blob/master/src/com/commonsware/cwac/colormixer/ColorMixer.java), it appears all you need to do is set up a listener/callback. This mechanism will allow you to get notified of any changes in the color picking.

First, have your class implement the following listener interface:

```
public interface OnColorChangedListener {
    public void onColorChange(int argb);
}
```

Then set the listener on the ColorMixer using:

```
public void setOnColorChangedListener(OnColorChangedListener listener) {
    this.listener=listener;
}
```

If you do it all inline, it will look somewhat like this:

```
mixer.setOnColorChangeListener(new ColorMixer.OnColorChangeListener() {
    @Override public void onColorChange(int argb) {
        //... get the color here; e.g.
        color = argb;
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time - found the answer, just have to wait 8 hours before answering my own question

Answer (score 0):

Thank you luksprog - it turned out it was crashing because I was trying to run the openColor method within a pop up window, and what I needed to do was not use a separate method and instead put the name of my pop up window (see [Android: popUp and button to dismiss doesnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595427))